# How to clear email form in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I am quite new in React and I've been stuck in this problem. When I send email address to mailchimp, I have still this address after sending. I tried to fix it but it's just a mess.

```js
class Newsletter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: ''
        };
    mySubmitHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        this.setState({email: ''});
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <form className="newsletter_form" onSubmit={this.mySubmitHandler} value={this.state.email}>
                <h1 style={{fontSize: 40, paddingTop: '10px'}}>Newsletter</h1>
                <p className="newsletter_info">Stay up to date with dance news in Oslo with us</p>
                <MailchimpSubscribe value="subscribe" url={process.env.REACT_APP_MAILCHIMP_URL} />
                <p className="newsletter_info">Your email is safe with us.</p> 
                <p className="newsletter_info"> We don't spam.</p>
            </form>
        )
    }
};
export default Newsletter;
```

Comment: I suggest you to use [`Formik`](https://formik.org/docs/overview). it has many awesome feature to control form data and its related actions. if you think it is hard to use, there is an alternative that name is [`react-form-hook`](https://react-hook-form.com/). Do not handle forms directly without using tools. it could make your codes dirty and hard to read.

Comment: email is empty the whole time?

Comment: The `form` element has no `value` attribute, it should be on an `input` ([doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a good tool for handling form data you can have a more readable and clean code.

```js
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const Newsletter App() {
  const { 
    reset, register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } 
  } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <button type="button" onClick={reset}>x</button>
      <input defaultValue="test" {...register("example")} />
      <input {...register("exampleRequired", { required: true })} />
      {errors.exampleRequired && <span>This field is required</span>}    
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

export default Newsletter;
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by adding:

```
 class Newsletter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: ''
        };
    }
    mySubmitHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        event.target.reset();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <form className="newsletter_form" onSubmit={this.mySubmitHandler.bind(this)}>

but thanks! :)
```

Comment: OK then, hope my post helped you, welcome to SO, I left two upvotes.